# Selecting distinct values by column value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| keyword                     | data_type |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| red                         | ctr       |
| blue                        | ctr       |
| purple                      | ctr       |
| orange                      | ctr       |
| red                         | var       |
| blue                        | var       |
| black                       | var       |
| yellow                      | var       |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

I'd like to be able to `select` only those which are `distinct` by `data_type`.

For example:
If I checked by `data_type`: `var`, '**black**' and '**yellow**' would be returned.

If I checked by `data_type`: `ctr`, '**purple**' and '**orange**' would be returned.

I'd normally provide an example query of what I've done, thus far, but I don't know where to start with this one - help is much appreciated.

Comment: please, add the desired result

Comment: I have? Happy to update if another format is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE data_type = 'var'
AND keyword NOT IN (SELECT keyword FROM table WHERE data_type <> 'var');
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect - seems so straight forward now. I'm going to write it out a few times to get it in my head